# How many bits are needed to commit one bit non-interactively in the standard model?

Tags: commitments

I'm wondering the state-of-art result about how many bits are needed to commit a single-bit non-interactively? I noticed in the paper of Naor's bit commitment: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/bit.pdf
this paper says assured amortized O(1) bits of communication per bit commitment. However, it seems Naor's bit commitment has interactive commitment phase. Thus I'm wondering the state-of-art result about this research direction. How many bits of communication per bit commitment should be sent non-interactively in the standard model?

I'm only interested in non-interactive bit commitment assuming one-way function not assuming DDH like Pedersen commitment.

Comment: The answer is not a constant number of bits, but a function of the security level. I'm not sure about what is asked: results for practical conjecturally secure systems like Pedersen commitment using an Elliptic Curve, or some theoretical bound?

Comment: @fgrieu I'm curious about the theoretical bound. Sorry for unclear question. Actually I meant the number of bits of communication for non-interactive bit commitment from one-way function in the standard model (i.e., without assuming random oracle or common reference string .etc)

Answer (score 2):

The state of the art regarding non-interactive bit commitment from OWF is quite simple: it is known to be impossible (at least using black box reductions) to build non-interactive commitments from one-way functions (see e.g. [this paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/NIC.pdf)).

Are you specifically interested in constructions from generic one-way function, or are you ok with more structured assumptions, such as one-way permutations (which *do* imply non-interactive commitments)? If you are also interested in OWP (or even one-to-one OWF), then I think the state-of-the-art generic construction of a NIBC is the direct application of the Goldreich-Levin theorem: to commit to $b$, given any OWP $f:\{0,1\}^n\mapsto \{0,1\}^n$, pick random $(x,r)$ and return $(f(x), r, \langle x, r\rangle \oplus b)$. The communication is $2n+1$ bit per bit committed. If you want to commit to a single bit, I do not know of any better solution. When amortizing, however, there might be better approaches - for example, you can at least commit to $\log(n)$ bits at once using a single $x$ and $\log(n)$ different $r$'s, lowering the communication to $n(1+o(1))$. I don't know if there is anything better generically (getting more hardcore bits from the Goldreich-Levin construction seems hopeless, but perhaps a completely different approach can help).

From collision resistant hash functions, at least, [this papers](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ivan_Damgard/publication/226369979_On_the_Existence_of_Statistically_Hiding_Bit_Commitment_Schemes_and_Fail-Stop_Signatures/links/0deec5195d386331c1000000/On-the-Existence-of-Statistically-Hiding-Bit-Commitment-Schemes-and-Fail-Stop-Signatures.pdf) provides a construction of a non-interactive commitment with $O(1)$ amortized communication - but their construction still requires a one-time interactive setup phase, the commitment scheme only becomes non-interactive after that.